# imread(openCV),QString unicodes

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("../赤月/lena.jpg");
if(img.empty()) std::cout<<"empty image"<<std::endl;
```

Or

```
QString const image_name = "../赤月/lena.jpg";
cv::Mat img = cv::imread(image_name_.toAscii().constData());
if(img.empty()) std::cout<<"empty image"<<std::endl;
```

The api of imread accept std::string, what if I need unicode support?

Comment: Why didn't you accept any answers in the past?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://code.opencv.org/issues/1268 (I guess you've actually tried to use the code in your question and it failed?)

Comment: I beg of your pardon,I didn't know I could accept the answer until you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Niko show me the link, I know how to solve the problem by Qt

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(codec);
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(codec);
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(codec);

QString const image_name = "../赤月/lena.jpg";
cv::Mat img = cv::imread(image_name_.toAscii().constData());
```

Now the codes work perfectly, thanks to all of you.