# OpenCV imread with foreign characters

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, utf-8, wstring

We're working on a project using OpenCV 2.4.6 and Qt 5.1.1 in C++. We have to load images for image processing at several points in our code, which we did using `cv::imread`, as normal. However, we wanted to make software compatible with other language filesystems, and found that having file paths with foreign characters would fail to load.

The problem, we believe, has to do with the fact that `imread` can only take in a `std::string` (or `char*`), and casting a path with non Latin-1 symbols to a `std::string` results in characters that use multiple bytes in UTF-8 (the encoding used for `QString`, which is how we store the paths) being converted to multiple chars.

To confirm that the file paths are valid, we've opened them by passing a `wstring` to a regular `ifstream`, which successfully opens the file and reads bits. Our current hack is to load the image as a `QImage` and then copy the data to a `cv::Mat`, but this isn't a satisfying solution, for multiple reasons, chiefly that as we understand it, `Qt::QImage` loads images in 8bit format, and our images are of a higher bit depth.

Is there any "clean" way to get around this? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375076/imreadopencv-qstring-unicodes) questions, but `toAscii` is deprecated, and its replacements didn't work for us. We've tried the following ways of converting the `QString` to a `std::string` and passing them to `imread`.

`QString::toStdString()`, `QString::toUtf8().data()`, `QString::toLocal8Bit().data()`, `QString::toLatin1().data()`. They all appear to yield roughly the same results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [opencv imread() on Windows for non-ASCII file names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769623/opencv-imread-on-windows-for-non-ascii-file-names)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `QString::toStdWString()` and then convert the resulting `std::wstring` to `std::string`.