# QString to std::string Unicode trouble

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, qt5, std

In this simple code I have trouble with Unicode:

```
QString qs = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0,"","","");
std::string str = qs.toUtf8().constData();
Mat m = imread(str);
```

When qs is Latin char set it works fine, but when path contains Cyrillic chars I obtain a bad conversion. As sample:
qs  "E:/Кирилиця_49.png":
str "E:/РљРёСЂРёР»РёС†СЏ_49.png"

I know that happens when str is not on UTF-8 characters set, but in project properties the "Character Set" property is "Use Unicode Character Set".
Compiler MSVC 2010, Qt 5.3.2. 
What could be the problem?

Comment: `QString` keeps data in unicode. So your conversion is OK. It doesn't depent on "Use Unicode Character Set" property at all. What is your question? Could you say, where exactly do you have a problem? In outputting to debug utf strings?

Comment: The problem is in str I receive "E:/РљРёСЂРёР»РёС†СЏ_49.png", but not  "E:/Кирилиця_49.png". This values I copies from debuger

Comment: Why not to use `QString::toStdString()` or rather `QString::toStdWString()`?

Comment: QString::toStdString() return bad chars too. toStdWString() works correct, but after I must convert it to std::string. and this can create a problem, because I use of C ++ 99 and not 11 and program runs under Linux, Windows and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `QString::toUtf8()` is doing its job right (modulo some bug in Qt's implementation...).

The problem could be that you are using a debugger visualizer for the content of `std::string` that is showing the string interpreting it using some *"code page"* instead of Unicode UTF-8.

Basically, the string content (as raw bytes) is correct (it's just the UTF-8 byte sequence corresponding to the original Unicode UTF-16 string): you are just using some "wrong-colored glasses" to look at it :)

The important point is: in what format does the `imread()` function expect its string parameter to be? If `imread()` expects an UTF-8 string, then you are right in passing a `std::string` with UTF-8 encoded string to it as argument.

Comment: > you are just using some "wrong-colored glasses" to look at it :)

Comment: Also to see correct string in debugger `str.c_str (), s8` could be used in case of msvc.

Comment: > you are just using some "wrong-colored glasses" to look at it :) - no because  imread(str) return NULL if path or file name contains Cyrillic chars. I think that codepage of std::string is not utf8. How can I change it to utf8? In qt4 I make QtextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("utf-8")), but in qt5 this function was obsolete.

Comment: > str.c_str (), s8 shows correct string. Mr.C64 was right. And now next question: why imread not work correctly with utf8 string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769623/opencv-imread-on-windows-for-non-ascii-file-names - the core of the my problem