# Opencv , imwrite, and unicode character problems.

Tags: python, opencv, unicode

It seems if my file path or file name has unicode characters, I can't use opencv's  imwrite method (no explicit error comes, but folders are empty).

I'm using Windows 7 and Python 3.6.

If I use non-unicode specific characters, the imwrite method will work fine.

The unicode-characters in question are greek letters:

`C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\TEMP\LRF Spinning Ένα διασκεδαστικό ψάρεμαδιάφορα ψάρια \image_459.jpg`

Is there some argument I can use to allow imwrite with unicode characters?

Thank you.

Comment: can you share code ? 

check if file path works as raw `r"filepath"` e.g . `r"C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\TEMP\LRF Spinning Ένα διασκεδαστικό ψάρεμαδιάφορα ψάρια \image_459.jpg"`

Comment: it is a well known problem of Opencv on Windows, look here for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24769623/4267439

Comment: @MaheshKaria  Thanks.  I will check if raw string works and get back to you (might take a bit as python is running a script).

Comment: @rok  I will check  out those solutions. Thank you.

Comment: The second dupe is for `imread`, but should help you for `imwrite` as well

Comment: @rok these are solutions for OpenCV C++, but it won't solve this problem which is OpenCV Python

Comment: @Miki, it is not straightforward from the proposed solutions, how to use imwrite (not imread) on python (not c++). OP Moondra, did you find a solution?

Comment: @MattS It's been a while but I don't think so. I think I remember just  catching an exception and  replacing the unicode characters with ascii characters