# Image doesn't get saved with "imwrite" function

Tags: python, windows, opencv

Hi I am learning opencv and the last part of the code, where I use the function `cv2imwrite` to save the processed image doesn't show up on any directory. Here is the code:

```
   # Canny Edge Detection

edges = cv2.Canny(image=img_blur, threshold1=100, threshold2=200) 

    # Saves Canny Edge Detection Image

cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/Gordenbúh/OneDrive/Escritorio/Hispatec/NaranjasCanny.png', edges)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    #This last part is to destroy some other images that I want to see but not keep
```

So the script runs fine, and I can see the image if I use `cv2.imshow`.

Thank you,

F

Comment: does it raise an Exception?

Comment: Try saving to your hard drive and not a cloud drive.

Comment: A couple of observations (assuming that path actually exists): non-ascii characters in a path is never a good idea. Now, backslashes have special meaning in string literals, if you want to use one you need to escape it: `'C:\\Users\\Gordenbúh\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\Hispatec\\NaranjasCanny.png'`. Also, `cv2.imwrite` returns a `bool` indicating if the write operation was successful or not, consider using that to check possible write errors.

Comment: the issue is `imwrite` and imread have issues with umlauts and other "weird" characters. I see that in the given path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [opencv imread() on Windows for non-ASCII file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769623/opencv-imread-on-windows-for-non-ascii-file-names)

Comment: This path "C:/Users/Gordenbúh/OneDrive/Escritorio/Hispatec" is valid? Have you ever created this directory?