# cv2.imread file with accent (unicode)

Tags: python, opencv, path, diacritics, os.path

I am trying to load the following file: `'data/chapter_1/capd_yard_signs\\Dueñas_2020.png'`

But when I do so, cv2.imread returns an error:  `imread_('data/chapter_1/capd_yard_signs\Due├▒as_2020.png'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity       load file`

When I specified the file name with os.path.join, I tried encoding and decoding the file

```
f = os.path.join("data/chapter_1/capd_yard_signs", filename.encode().decode())
```

But that didn't solve the problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: known problem that OpenCV has with unicode file names. -- workaround: read file contents, then use `imdecode`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [opencv imread() on Windows for non-ASCII file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769623/opencv-imread-on-windows-for-non-ascii-file-names)

Comment: Gotcha. Didn't know that. I'll try reading the file content than use imdecode. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I ended up getting it to work:

```
from PIL import Image
pil = Image.open(f).convert('RGB') # load the image with pillow and make sure it is in RGB
pilCv = np.array(pil) # convert  the image to an array
img = pilCv[:,:,::-1].copy() # convert the array to be in BGR
```

Comment: Seems rather pointless pulling in yet another dependency, when you already have OpenCV, numpy and Python standard libraries available, that provide several ways to accomplish this. e.g. `cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile('foo.png', dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`

Answer (score 0):

This shall work:

```
import cv2, numpy as np

pic = cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(os.path.join("data/chapter_1/capd_yard_signs", filename).replace('\\','/'), dtype=np.uint8), 0)
```

`np.fromfile` reads the non-ASCII characters first,
`.replace('\\','/')` should also solve your nonuniform / and \ issue. Then `imdecode` does its work.

Here it is for grayscale. For colour, replace 0 with `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR`.

Comment: the slash replacement makes no difference. `np.fromfile` is a required dependency of OpenCV for Python, so this is okay to depend on (vs. PIL which is not already required).

Comment: Probably true, will check it later.