# Can't open an image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I couldn't open different images with OpenCV altough I could open with PIL by the way I tried to open these images in PyCharm and in Spyder.How can I fix this problem? I deleted and reinstalled OpenCV but it didn't work.

OpenCv Verssion: 4.8.0.76
Python Version:3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\ozber\OneDrive\Masaüstü\images\kullan.jpg")
cv2.imshow("resim",image)
```

this is the code which I wrote.

Error message from PyCharm:

```
[ WARN:0@0.025] global loadsave.cpp:248 cv::findDecoder imread_('C:\Users\ozber\OneDrive\Masaüstü\images\kullan.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ozber\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.2\scratches\openCv.py", line 6, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("resim",image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Error Message from Spyder:

```
runfile('C:/Users/ozber/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/ozber/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\ozber\.spyder-py3\temp.py:6
    cv2.imshow("resim",image)

error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'



[ WARN:0@665.556] global loadsave.cpp:248 cv::findDecoder imread_('C:\Users\ozber\OneDrive\Masa端st端\images\kullan.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
```

but this code which I wrote in PIL works very well.

```
from PIL import Image

img=Image.open(r"C:\Users\ozber\OneDrive\Masaüstü\images\kullan.jpg")
img.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried if the image loads correctly when the path does not contain special characters (`ü`in this case)

Comment: Thank you a lot.I changed name of the masaüstü folder as a "desktop" and it worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [opencv imread() on Windows for non-ASCII file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769623/opencv-imread-on-windows-for-non-ascii-file-names)

Answer (score 1):

I had problem like this. And after two days of search for information, I realized that I just need to use only Latin letters. Try not to use other characters (ü, 端) in the path description. I think it's can help